# How to cut string of characters into a structure array [C]?

Tags: c, structure

I implemented a program to cut string of characters (taken from the command line argument) into a structure of array. Yet, I am having some troubles running my program correctly. Precisely, I don't know what the output to expect or how to code the main function in order to check the program correctly.

Input to the function is given in the following format:
***Age|Name;Age2|Name2;Age3|Name3***

for example, when I compile my program with

***-g -Wall -Wextra -Werror***

and run the program as follows

***./a.out "23|Marcin;"***

I get the following output:

***AWAVI��AUATL�%�***

***21934***

Thanks for the help regarding the way how I could test it.

**ft_destruct.c file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ft_perso.h"

/*Function that takes string and determines the age variable*/
int     ft_get_age(char *str)
{
  int age;

  age = 0;
  while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9')
    {
      age = (age * 10) + (*str - '0');
      ++str;
    }
  return (age);
}

/*Function that determines the length of the string *name*, in order
to allocate the necessary memory for the char *name in the function
below*/
int     ft_str_malloc_length(char *str)
{
  int length;
  
  length = 0;
  while (*str)
    {
      if (*str == '|')
    {
      while (*str != ';')
        length++;
    }
      ++str;
    }
  return (length);
}
/*Function that takes determines the name part from the command line
input and stores in the char array *name. */
char    *ft_get_name(char *str)
{
  char *name;
  int length;
  int i;

  length = ft_str_malloc_length(str);
  name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
  i = 0;
  while (*str)
    {
      if (*str == '|')
    {
      while (*str != ';')
        {
          *name = *str;
          ++name;
          ++str;
        }
    }
      ++str;
    }
  *(name + 1) = '\0';
  return (name);
}

/*Function that takes the name and age variables and stores them in
the array of structure*/
t_perso     **ft_create_struct_arr(int nmb_of_struct, char *str)
{
  int i;
  t_perso **arr; //Structure is defined in the file "ft_perso.h", below.

  arr = (t_perso **)malloc(sizeof(t_perso *) * (nmb_of_struct + 1));
  i = 0;
  while (*str)
    {
      arr[i]->age = ft_get_age(str);
      arr[i]->name = ft_get_name(str);
      ++str;
      i++;      
    }
  return (arr);
}

t_perso     **ft_decrypt(char *str) 
{
  int i;
  int nmb_of_struct;

  i = 0;
  nmb_of_struct = 0;
  while (*str)
    {
      if (*str == ';')
    nmb_of_struct++;
      ++str;
    }
  return (ft_create_struct_arr(nmb_of_struct, str));
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  int i;

  i = ac;
  t_perso arr[1];
  ft_decrypt(*av);
  printf("%s\n", arr[0].name);
  printf("%d\n", arr[1].age);
  return (0);
}
```

**ft_perso.h file**

```
#ifndef FT_PERSO_H
# define FT_PERSO_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SAVE_THE_WORLD "SAVE_THE_WORLD"

typedef struct{
  char *name;
  float life;
  int age;
  char *profession;
} t_perso;

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is *"Why am I getting the following error:
`ft_decrpyt.c:108:18: error: storage size of 'perso' isn’t known struct t_perso perso;`"*, the answer is this:

In `main` replace

```
struct t_perso perso;
```

with

```
t_perso perso;
```

`t_perso` is already a `struct`.